# JAVA - get attribute from class to list

Tags: java, class, attributes, jcombobox

I have a class called "Sprache" and need a attribute "getSprache", who is a get methode. I want to display all "getSprache" to a Jcombobox. I actually have a DefaultComboboxModel.
How can I do it?
Do I need a list?
How looks a loop for the model?

```
public class Sprache {

private int id;
private String sprache;
private String kuerzel;

public int getId() {
    return id;
}
public String getSprache() {
    return sprache;
}
public String getKuerzel() {
    return kuerzel;
}
private void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}
private void setSprache(String sprache) {
    this.sprache = sprache;
}
private void setKuerzel(String kuerzel) {
    this.kuerzel = kuerzel;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Sprache [id=" + id + ", sprache=" + sprache + ", kuerzel=" + kuerzel + "]";
}
```

}

Comment: I'm irritated. So you have several Sprache objects to put into a JComboBox or just one with different Strings or do you want to split that String up?

Comment: What does `sprache` contain? A single language or a list of several languages? Do you have a `List<Sprache>` somewhere? Currently this question is pretty unclear.

Comment: I want to display only the Strings, String sprache contains the language also like english, german, italian. It should be a list of serveral languages to select.

Comment: You can get a list with all the Sprachen and then update the comboBox

Comment: So the class Sprache is for one language? Then you need to instantiate a Sprache class for each language and store it in an array (or only the strings by calling #toString()). This List can then be used in teh combobox.

Answer (score 0):

If your class Sprache contains one "Sprache" (language), then you can iterate through all of them and call #getSprache() on each and store the return value in an String array:

```
// Instantiate Classes
Sprache sprache1 = new Sprache();
sprache1.setId(0);
sprache1.setKuerzel("EN");
sprache1.setSprache("English");

Sprache sprache2 = new Sprache();
sprache2.setId(1);
sprache2.setKuerzel("DE");
sprache2.setSprache("Deutsch");

List<Sprache> sprachen = new ArrayList<>(2);
sprachen.add(sprache1);
sprachen.add(sprache2);

// Create an array from the langues
String sprachenStringArray[] = {sprache1.getSprache(), sprache2.getSprache()};
// Alternative way
String sprachenStringArray[] = new String[sprachen.size()];
for (int i = 0; i < sprachen.size(); i++)
{
    sprachenStringArray[i] = sprachen.get(i).getSprache();
}

// Create combo box model
DefaultComboBoxModel<String> model = new DefaultComboBoxModel<>(sprachenStringArray);
```